# getting n-gram counts at id-level for multiple documents per id (tokenize documents then aggregate or tokenizer skip parameter)

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, token, tokenize

I have a dataframe of ids and text, and would like to get n-gram counts per id (e.g. an id-term matrix).

As an example, let's i want bi-grams (2-grams) for the following table

```
+-----+------------------+
| id  |   text           |
+-----+------------------+
| id1 | quick with fox   |
| id1 | brown fox        |
| id1 | quick squirrel   |
| id2 | yes its great    |
| id2 | fun with fox     |
| id3 | horr time        |
+-----+------------------+
```

In this case, the desired 2-gram counts looks like (*isn't necessarily binary*)

```
+-----+------------+----------+-----------+----------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|     | quick with | with fox | brown fox | quick squirrel | yes its | its great | fun with | horr time |
+-----+------------+----------+-----------+----------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| id1 |          1 |        1 |         1 |              1 |       0 |         0 |        0 |         0 |
| id2 |          0 |        1 |         0 |              0 |       1 |         1 |        1 |         0 |
| id3 |          0 |        0 |         0 |              0 |       0 |         0 |        0 |         1 |
+-----+------------+----------+-----------+----------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

This has to run efficiently for 1mil rows, 100-300k unique ids, and text that can range from 3 characters to 20+ words (e.g. a paragraph).

Two methods I've tried/proposed are

1. Tokenize at document level then groupBy, then Sum

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df = 3, ngram_range=(2,2))
X_bow_sp = vectorizer.fit_transform(df["text"])
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

bow_df = pd.DataFrame(X_bow_sp)
bow_ids_df = pd.concat([df['id'], bow_df], axis=1, ignore_index=False, sort=False)
id_term_df = bow_ids_df.groupby('id')[vocab].sum()
```

This is way **too slow**. Specifically, the last line sum.

2. Concatenate text at group level (e.g. separated by '|'), but how to break apart n-gram?

```
id_text_df = df.groupby(['id'])['text'].apply(lambda x: ' | '.join(x))
```

What next? How can I feed a tokenizer option that breaks a potential n-gram apart when it encounters a `|`?

I'm using python/pandas primarily at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Solution #2 should work if joining on " " not "|".

'''
id_text_df = df.groupby(['id'])['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
'''

Then for example the row for id1 will read:
quick with fox brown fox quick squirrel

Comment: the point of the delimiter would be to skip the creation of n-grams with words on both sides of the delimiter since they are not from the same document. most tokenizers by default remove punctuations and tokenize words based on whitespace separation so that's not really the issue at hand.

Comment: e.g. I dont want 'fox brown', 'fox quick', or 'great fun' as bigrams in the example